# How to handle changing the format of a PyPi version number

Tags: python, pypi

My project Pyrr was previously using versions that were datestamps.

The last datestamped version was:

```
version='20130321'
```

I want to move to a proper `major.minor.micro` format.

I've updated a new package to PyPi in this format.

```
version='0.1.0'
```

When I `pip install pyrr` I still get the `20130321` version.

```
$ yolk -V pyrr
pyrr 0.1.0

$ pip install pyrr
Downloading/unpacking pyrr
  Downloading pyrr-20130321.tar.gz
<snip>
```

PyPi has the over versions marked as hidden and the `0.1.0` as the only version not marked hidden.

What do I have to do to get pip / pypi to download the 0.1.0 version instead of the older datestamp versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`20130321` is the major version, which is obviously higher than `0`, therefor version `20130321` is considered the latest version.

The easiest way to fix this would be to delete the outdated version using the [webinterface](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=pyrr).

If the older versions should still exist, you could download them and reupload them using a newer version. e.g. `0.0.20130321`.

If people depend on your package without a version, they wouldn't notice the new versioning system.

If people do depend on a specific version, they would have to change their version dependency. This could be considered annoying, but it is inevitable and it's a small change for them.

Comment: Yeah I realise that 20xxx > 0.0. But PyPi acknowledges that 0.1.X is the newest one. I guess it's so you can upload older versions (maintenance fixes for older releases) without nuking newer install bases. From that point of view its behaviour makes sense.